# Hide component name from url in navigator

Tags: reactjs

how hide the name of components i have when i enter to him from url like http://localhost:3000/ParametrageAgence . jsx, how hide this part ParametrageAgence . jsx also do some encode or something

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React router` in that package when you use `<BrowserRouter>` it hides the file extension

- here is the link for react router documentation

  - https://reactrouter.com/en/main